What does the superposition in the delayed choice quantum eraser experiment look like?
Suppose that we have a double slit experiment, and we fire particles through the double slit and a detector records their position. For simplicity, let's say the screen is partitioned into two areas $A$ and $B$, such that when there is an interference pattern, we get we get $A$ with a probability of $.75$ and $B$ with a probability of $.25$, while when there is no interference pattern, the probability is $.50$ for both. This detector then prints one of the two letters on a sheet of paper.
Additionally, we set up a second detector on the slits, which prints either $X$ or $Y$ on a separate sheet of paper, depending on which of the two slits the particle passed through. We repeat the experiment $100$ times, getting $100$ letters printed out on each sheet.
According to the delayed quantum eraser experiment, if we choose to destroy the paper holding the information of which slit was taken, and then read the second paper, we are likely to see close to $75$ $A$'s and $25$ $B$'s written on the second sheet, matching the interference pattern, while if we choose not to destroy it, we get are likely to see a similar amount of $A$'s and $B$'s on the second sheet.
But before we made the choice of destroying or not the sheet of paper, the results are in a superposition of all possible results assigning a probability amplitude for each (for example, one of them will be $|XYXXY...XY,ABBAB...BA\rangle$). How can we calculate what the coefficients for each result will be?

In general the DCQE expt has been debunked ... see wikipedia, it's not worth wasting your time on.  In all interference experiments, if you interact with the photon/electron along the way, you change the experiment fundamentally and interference is easily destroyed.

Let's analyse it step by step. First, we have two basis, the slit basis $|X\rangle,|Y\rangle$ and the result basis $|A\rangle,|B\rangle$. When there is no interference, the probability of A and B are equal, which means
$$
|X\rangle = x_a|A\rangle + x_b |B\rangle
$$
$$
|Y\rangle = y_a |A\rangle + y_b|B\rangle.
$$
With $|x_a|^2=|x_b|^2=|y_a|^2=|y_b|^2=0.5$. The matrix
$$
U =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_a & y_a\\
x_b & y_b
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Is the changing basis matrix and it's orthogonal. It is defined up to four phases, but since the global phase factor is not relevant, we only need to set three phase factors. The orthogonality condition fix another phase, and we know that
$$
\sqrt{1\over 2}(|X\rangle + |Y\rangle) = \sqrt{1\over 2}(x_a+y_a)|A\rangle + \sqrt{1\over 2}(x_b+y_b)|B\rangle \equiv \sqrt{0.75}|A\rangle + \sqrt{0.25}|B\rangle
$$
With it, we completely caracterize the interferometer and could define all phases in $U$. The only important thing is that $|X\rangle = U|A\rangle$ and $|Y\rangle = U|B\rangle$.
The path discriminator
It is an ancillary system that becomes entangled with the particle after the slits, and the joint state becomes
$$
|\psi\rangle = \sqrt{1\over 2} |X\rangle |D_x\rangle + \sqrt{1\over 2} |Y\rangle |D_y\rangle
$$
If we change the particle basis to the result basis, it can be written as
$$
|\psi\rangle = \sqrt{1\over 2} |A\rangle (U|D_x\rangle) + \sqrt{1\over 2}|B\rangle (U|D_y\rangle).
$$
Now, we can make some questions.
What happens when we measure over the discriminator?
Well, if we measure $|D_x\rangle$ we project the state so
$$
(\mathbb I \otimes |D_x\rangle\!\langle D_x|)|\psi\rangle \propto |X\rangle
$$
It means that when the detector fires $D_x$, the particle passed the slit $x$ and vice-versa. The detector is perfect correlated with the particle, so we always discover the path measuring over the discriminator. But the interference vanishes.
What happens when we don't measure the discriminator?
The interference pattern also vanishes. It is easy to see it, using the relative state of the particle tracing out the discriminator
$$
\rho_P = {1\over 2}|A\rangle\!\langle A| + {1\over 2}|B\rangle\!\langle B|
$$
This is an important result showing that is not the act of measuring which destroys the interference pattern, but the mere possibility to have the which path information available.
Erasuring the path information
If we decide to measure the discriminator in a different basis, it is possible to recover the initial interference pattern. It means that there exist $|D_\pm\rangle$ such that
$$
\psi = \left( \sqrt{0.75}|A\rangle + \sqrt{0.25}|B\rangle\right)|D_+\rangle + \left( \sqrt{0.25}|A\rangle - \sqrt{0.75}|B\rangle\right(|D_-\rangle.
$$
Comparing this expression with the previous one, you can explicit find such basis. Now if we measure $D_+$, we recover the interference pattern, but if we measure $D_-$ we recover a complementary interference pattern. Again, if we do nothing, there is no interference.
What means delayed choice?
To observe the interference pattern, we need to measure in the result basis of the particle, i.e., to realize $|A\rangle\!\langle A|\otimes \mathbb I$. Since this measurement commutes with any measurement over the discriminator, it means that in practice it could be done before we decide the discriminator basis, i.e., before to decide if we would erase the path information or not.

All that I said could be described in terms of probability. Initially, you have a setup where $P(A)= 0.75$ means that you have interference and $P(A)=0.5$ means you don't. After inserting the path discriminator, you have $P(A|D_x)=0.5$, which means that you don't have interference anymore, but more than that, the marginal $P(A)=0.5$, indicating that the mere presence of the discriminator destroys interference even if you don't measure it. The erasure process means that you can recover the interference conditionally, i.e., $P(A|D_+)=0.75$. Now, delayed choice means that the correlations $P(A,D_x)$ and $P(A,D_+)$ are symmetric about temporal ordering, which indicates that the measurement $A$ could be realized before we decide to measure $D_x$ or $D_+$, the probabilities will be the same.
